# How to use Delegated permissions for Azure AD app without signed-in user?

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to use Delegated permissions to access API **without** a signed-in user?

What does the signed-in user exactly mean?

If I signed in to my Azure AD from Powershell using `Connect-AzureAD`, will I comes under signed-in user?

If that's the case, when I give Delegated permissions to access API , I'm still getting 403 Forbidden error.

But if I assign Application Permissions, I'm able to access the API and make the calls without any hurdle.

Can anyone elaborate on this and make me understand what's actually happening?

Answer (score 1):

> If I signed in to my Azure AD from Powershell using Connect-AzureAD,
> will I comes under signed-in user?
> Yes , as you get microsoft login and you then signin as the user.
> For that you require delegated permissions being granted as they are necessary when you want to call the Web API as the `logged on user`.

- *Application permissions are used when the application have to call the API as itself.it does not depend on which user is signed in.The
  api can be called without the user. but it needs application
  permissions being granted.*
- Application permissions do not require a user to login.If you
  attempt to access the api without the application permissions
  without even  authenticated user's token you will receive 401 errors,
  you will be  facing errors